# How to prevent forms from emptying inputs by submiting the form in html?

Tags: php, html, forms, validation, submit

I'm writing a form in using php and html.
This form has validation control.
when I submit the form all the textboxes get empty and if the user has filled for example 3 of 5 inputs , because if those two inputs he/she now has to fill those 3 inputs again.
How can I prevent the form from emptying the inputs by submitting the form?

Comment: do you want to repopulate form after submit?

Comment: you can use sessions and/or Ajax.

Comment: if you want to repopulate and if your target is same page then just use $_REQUEST array to repopulate. add some html and your php code for more clarification

Comment: Well I just want to keep texts that the user has wrote before submitting the form after the form has submited.

Comment: ternary operator then and what I already mentioned above.

Comment: well in that case you can use session as well as $_REQUEST array. please add some php and html code

Comment: validation should happen before submit.

Comment: ok, so this tells us you're using your form and PHP in the same file. You're going to need to show us some code here. It's starting to be guesswork and a whole bunch of suggestions. There isn't more I can suggest here.

Comment: OP is still validating, just wants to retain data @VigneswaranS

Comment: Mohammad: If you show us your code, or some sample code, we can make the obvious suggestions. Its not difficult, but its easier to explain using your existing code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you validation script and form code are in this same file you can just put $_POST values into form.

```
<?php
$field1 = '';
$field2 = '';
...
$field5 = '';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST"){
    $field1 = $_POST['field1'];
    $field2 = $_POST['field2'];
    ...
    $field5 = $_POST['field5'];

    if(validation is true){
     //do something
    }
}
    ?>

    <form method="post">
       <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?= $field1 ?>" >
       <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?= $field2 ?>" >
        ...
       <input type="text" name="field5" value="<?= $field5 ?>" >
       <input type="submit" value="submit" >
    </form>
```

EDITED after comment RiggsFolly.

Comment: I am afraid this will actually generate errors when the page is first loaded from a link or using the browser address bar, as then `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=="POST")` will be FALSE and therefore you wont create the `$fields1` variables. __Use a ternary operator instead__ or include an `isset()` on each fields in the html section

Answer (score 0):

check if form field is set in $_REQUEST array or not, print its value accordingly

```
<form method="post">
    <input type="text" name="field1" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST["field1"])? $_REQUEST["field1"]:""?>" >
    <input type="text" name="field2" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST["field2"])? $_REQUEST["field2"]:""?>" >
    ...
    <input type="text" name="field5" value="<?php echo (isset($_REQUEST["field5"])? $_REQUEST["field5"]:""?>" >
    <input type="submit" value="submit" >
</form>
```

Answer (score -2):

i thought of javascript:

```
function validateForm() {
     var x = document.forms["myForm"]["fname"].value;
     if (x == null || x == "") {
         alert("Name must be filled out");
         return false;
     }
 }
```

You can find all about is on: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

It works great, when user lets the field empty, it will say: "Name must be filled out". The submit will do nothing until you fill that...

//sorry for bad english

Comment: This isn't about validation. It is about retaining the form data.

Comment: But you still have to validate on the server as its quite easy to turn javascript OFF or send data to the server without even looking at the form

Comment: Well, but then, it is bad asked question :)

Comment: Of course, it couldn't be that! Maybe! Possibly! Probably Not!!!