# CodeIgniter showing correct URL if validation error occurred in edit form

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a controller with edit method and my edit URL like

```
http://localhost/pothdekhun/road/edit/3
```

When any server side error occurred then with following code i am showing same form with errors

```
if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
   //this is loading edit view form
   $this->nuts_lib->view_loader('user', 'add', $data, TRUE, 'latest_routes', 'rightbar');
   return;
}
```

Now my problem is in URL and the `URL` showing like (When error in edit form)

```
http://localhost/pothdekhun/road/edit
```

As we know redirect not possible here with validation error messages. Now how can I can resolve this issue??

So I want URL like `http://localhost/pothdekhun/road/edit/3` with validation messages. Will I change my edit form action like `site_url('road/edit/').$route_id` OR any better idea??

Comment: is your form atction is the same page?

Comment: to do this i think you need to set form action to same page like what you said in question site_url('road/edit/').$route_id

Comment: there is problem with my mentioned way. the hidden field's value lost in view page

Comment: you may have hidden fields values in $_REQUEST array, try to update values by checking isset($_REQUEST['field_name'])?$_REQUEST['field_name']:"" to hidden inputs

Comment: for hidden fields check my answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319727/how-to-prevent-forms-from-emptying-inputs-by-submiting-the-form-in-html/34320132#34320132

Comment: @Farhan. Thanks. Got an idea `<input type="hidden" id="route_id" name="route_id" value="<?php if($this->input->post('route_id')){echo set_value('route_id');}else{ echo isset($route['id']) ? $route['id'] : '';} ?>"/>`

Answer (score 1):

As per discussion you was facing issue with missing values for hidden fields on submit form and if there are form errors. please follow my answer for this to get values after form submit.
[How to prevent forms from emptying inputs by submiting the form in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34319727/how-to-prevent-forms-from-emptying-inputs-by-submiting-the-form-in-html/34320132#34320132)